# How to replace AsyncTask Executor with RxJavaHooks?

Tags: android, retrofit, rx-java

I'm new to RxJava and am on RxJava 1.2.2. I use AsnycTask Executor for my RetroFit call like this:

```
public Observable<SomeObject> getSomeObject(String id) {
    return anyService.getSomeObject(id)
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.from(AsyncTask.THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR))
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread());
}
```

So far if I wanted to replace any Scheduler with Schedulers.immediate() for my tests, the solution was RxJavaSchedulersHook. An example here:

[RxSchedulersOverrideRule.java](https://github.com/ribot/android-boilerplate/blob/master/app/src/test/java/uk/co/ribot/androidboilerplate/util/RxSchedulersOverrideRule.java)

But AFAIK this doesn't help with a Scheduler created with from() from an Executor. And is deprecated in favor of RxJavaHooks. It seems you have to use RxJavaHooks.onScheduleAction(...), but I'm not experienced enough to figure out how to use this to accomplish my goal and couldn't find a solution anywhere.

Hence the question in the title.

Answer (score 1):

Forget RxJavaHooks and use that.

```
public class RxSchedulersOverrideRule implements TestRule {

    @Override
    public  Statement apply(final Statement base, Description description) {
        return new Statement() {
            @Override
            public  void evaluate() throws Throwable {
                RxAndroidPlugins.reset();
                RxAndroidPlugins.setMainThreadSchedulerHandler(scheduler -> Schedulers.trampoline());

                RxJavaPlugins.reset();
                RxJavaPlugins.setIoSchedulerHandler(scheduler -> Schedulers.trampoline());
                RxJavaPlugins.setComputationSchedulerHandler(scheduler -> Schedulers.trampoline());
                RxJavaPlugins.setNewThreadSchedulerHandler(scheduler -> Schedulers.trampoline());

                base.evaluate();

                RxAndroidPlugins.reset();
                RxJavaPlugins.reset();
            }
        };
    }
}
```